# Is List.rev acting strangely?

Tags: list, functional-programming, append, ocaml, reverse

I'm new to OCaml and attempting to implement `List.append` as a learning exercise. This is what I have:

```
let rec append a b =
    match (List.rev a) with
       []       -> b
       | x:: xs -> append xs (x::b)
```

This seems to work until argument `a` has more than two elements. Example:

```
# append [1;2] [3;4] 
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
# append [1;2;3] [4;5;6]
- : int list = [2; 1; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

What's going on here? I've checked, and `List.rev [1;2;3]` returns `int list = [3; 2; 1]`. I know my implementation is naïve and not (yet) lazy, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Did you use the `ocamldebug` debugger? Did you look into the [free as in speech] source code of *Ocaml* (in `ocaml-3.12/stdlib/list.ml`) for the code of `List.rev` ??

Comment: I am in the debugger now, but not seeing any obvious leads. I did look at the source and convinced myself that the implementation of `List.rev` should act as I expect it to. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at start of your `append`, or some printing stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you think about it, you are reversing your first list quite a few times.  Probably more than you wanted to.

You can see what's happening if you follow the steps of an example.

```
append [1; 2; 3] []
(* match binds x to 3, xs to [2; 1] *)
append [2; 1] [3]
(* match binds x to 1, xs to [2] *)
append [2] [1; 3]
(* match binds x to 2, xs to [] *)
append [] [2; 1; 3]
(* done *)
```

Comment: Ah duh! How foolish of me! So a correct version would have two functions `rev_append` and `append`, where `append a b` is simply `rev_append (List.rev a) b`.

Comment: That would work, it's little ornate though!  The implementation in pervasives.ml is simpler (but not tail recursive).  Since this is an exercise for you I won't burden you with my own implementation.

Comment: Oh double duh... I can just not reverse the list at all and do `x::xs -> x :: append xs b` for the second pattern.

Comment: Yes, this is how it's done in Pervasives, where its name is (@).  Regards.